# Find the product of 2 lines

Tags: geometry

There is a circle with center $O$. $C$ is a point on the circle. $AB$ is its diameter. $H$ is a point on $AB$ and $CH$ is orthogonal to $AB$, moreover $AH = 8$ and $HB= 18$.

There is a tangent line at $C$. Please find, the product of $AL$ and $BM$ where $L$ and $M$ are point on the tangent line such that $AL$ and $BM$ are orthogonal to the tangent line.

And also please help me find angel LHM.

I tried the following.

The radius $r = 13$. $OH = 5$, and I also found that $CH = 12$.

But I cannot go on in order to find a solution to the whole problem.

Comment: After drawing a figure, I strongly suspect that the quadrilaterals $AHCL$ and $BMCH$ are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$\angle{LCA}=\angle{HBC},\quad \angle{MCB}=\angle{HAC}$$
we know that $\triangle{LCA}$ and $\triangle{HBC}$ are similar, and that $\triangle{MCB}$ and $\triangle{HAC}$ are similar.

Hence, since we can have
$$AL:CH=CA:BC\quad\Rightarrow \quad AL=\frac{CA}{BC}CH$$
$$BM:CH=BC:CA\quad\Rightarrow \quad BM=\frac{BC}{CA}CH$$
we have
$$AL\times BM=CH^2.$$

---

**Added** : Since $\angle{CHB}+\angle{CMB}=180^\circ$, we know that the four points $H,C,M,B$ are on a circle. Similarly, since $\angle{CHA}+\angle{CLA}=180^\circ$, we know that the four points $C,L,A,H$ are on a circle. Thus, we have
$$\angle{CMH}=\angle{CBH}=\angle{LCA},\quad\angle{CLH}=\angle{CAH}=\angle{MLB}.$$
Hence, $$\angle{LHM}=180^\circ-\angle{CMH}-\angle{CLH}=180^\circ-\angle{LCA}-\angle{MLB}=180^\circ-90^\circ=90^\circ.$$

Comment: Could you please explain why we have this ∠LCA=∠HBC,∠MCB=∠HAC?

Comment: @Marie: Alternate segment theorem. See, for example, [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/).

Comment: Yes sure, thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you also help me find angel LHM? From my drawing it's obvious that it is 90 degrees, but could you please provide a geometrical approach?

Comment: @Marie: I added a bit. Have a look.

Comment: Please tell me why L and M are on a circle.

Comment: @Marie: Since $\angle{CHB}+\angle{CMB}=180^\circ$, the quadrilateral $CHBM$ is a [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral). Similarly, the quadrilateral $CLAH$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.